# Applescript for keyboard system preferences pane

Tags: keyboard, applescript, preferences

I'm trying to write an applescript to get me to a specific section of the system preferences - Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts and click on the "+", choose a specific app, enter Menu Title and enter "F key" in to their respective fields. Here is what I have so far:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        click radio button "Shortcuts" of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard" of application process "System Preferences"
        delay 1
        select row 8 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
        click radio button "+" of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard" of application process "System Preferences"
    end tell
end tell
```

This gets me to the App Shortcuts portion of the Keyboard prefs pane, but I can't click on the "+" button to go further. Is there a way to click on "+", choose an application, fill in the Menu Title and Keyboard Shortcut fields?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not need your **AppleScript** *code* as this provides a complete and proper solution for the **UI Scripting** of **System Preferences** for the use case you are wanting to achieve.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Note that because this is using **UI Scripting**, it is necessary to allow it to run without doing anything else until the *script* finishes.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is commented and you should only need to set the value of the menu item title, application name, and keyboard shortcut based on the coded *example* using **Photos**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Set the value for appName and menuItemTitle, as in the example below.

set appName to "Photos"
set menuItemTitle to "Keep Sorted By Title"

--  # Set the keyboard shortcut in the setKeyboardShortcut() handler.

to setKeyboardShortcut()
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        keystroke "t" using {option down, command down}
end setKeyboardShortcut



--  ######################################################
--  # The code below should only be edited as necessary. #
--  ######################################################


--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.

set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
    ".GlobalPreferences.plist"

--  # Get the value of AppleKeyboardUIMode to determine if the
--  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
--  # checkbox is checked on the System Preferences >  
--  # Keyboard > Shortcuts tab.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        set keyboardNavigation to the value of ¬
            the property list item "AppleKeyboardUIMode"

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Check the checkbox.
    my toggleKeyboardNavagition()
end if

--  # Open System Preferences to the 
--  # Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard pane.

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of ¬
        application process "System Preferences"
        
        --  # Wait until necessary UI element is available.
        
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists ¬
            checkbox 1 of ¬
            tab group 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat
        
        --  # Select App Shortcuts.
        --  # This is wrapped in a try 
        --  # statement as a workaround.
        
        try
            select (rows of ¬
                table 1 of ¬
                scroll area 1 of ¬
                splitter group 1 of ¬
                tab group 1 whose ¬
                value of ¬
                static text 1 is ¬
                "App Shortcuts")
        end try
        
        --  # Wait until necessary UI element is available.
        
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists ¬
            button 1 of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            tab group 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat
        
        --  # Click the [+] button.
        
        click button 1 of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            tab group 1
        
        --  # Wait until necessary UI element is available.
        
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists ¬
            text field 2 of sheet 1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat
        
        --  # Fill in the Sheet with the menu item title,
        --  # application name, and keyboard shortcut.
        
        set value of text field 2 of sheet 1 to menuItemTitle
        delay 0.2
        click pop up button 1 of sheet 1
        delay 0.2
        click menu item appName of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of sheet 1
        delay 0.2
        key code 48 --  # Tab key
        delay 0.2
        my setKeyboardShortcut()
        delay 0.2
        click button "Add" of sheet 1
        
    end tell
end tell

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Uncheck the checkbox if it
    --  # was previously unchecked.
    my toggleKeyboardNavagition()
end if

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit


--  # Handler #

--  # Toggles checkbox: 'Use keyboard navigation 
--  # to move focus between controls'

on toggleKeyboardNavagition()
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of ¬
            pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of ¬
            application process "System Preferences"
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of tab group 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1
        end tell
    end tell
end toggleKeyboardNavagition
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>